# Package visibility before Android 11 when targetSdkVersion = 30

Tags: android

When targetSdk=30, package visibility restrictions applied only on Android 11 or they applied on all versions of Android?

It is unclear from the documentation.

Comment: Only for Android 11 devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 11 and above only.

How would the behavior of old devices change without updating the underlying platform software? Target SDK setting controls *backward* compatibility modes in new platform versions.